# JetpackCompese最新版(1.6.1)でもTextFieldの余白(innerPadding)は消せないのか

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

## 環境

AndroidStudio Hedgehoge
JetpackCompose 1.6.1

## 質問

JetpackComposeの`TextField`にデフォルトで設定されている`innerPadding`を無効化、削除、もしくは変更したいです。
自分で調べた限り、カスタムレイアウトを定義する以外では不可能なようなのですが、いまいち確証が持てません。

最新版においても、`BasicTextField`を使用するしか方法はないのでしょうか。

[image: ここの余白です]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

確証を持って不可能と言えるようになりました。

1. `TextField`内部の`BasicTextField`で設定されている`TextFieldDecolationBox`の`contentPadding`引数が設定されていない
2. `BasicTextField`の`Modifier.defaultMinSize`に引っかかる

以上の2つが原因で、どちらも外部から設定することはできません。
そのため、カスタムレイアウトとしてそれらを定義した`TextField`を作成するしかないようです。